# How do I make an item change colours in Minecraft with only one texture?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs, minecraft-resource-packs, minecraft-optifine

I want to make an item use a single greyed out texture to be any colour, much like leather armour.
I would do this with OptiFine but I don't know if it supports that or how I would even do that.
All I know is that I want to use the item's NBT data from this path

> **Item.tag.armElyData.chestplate.tag.display.color**

to do it. The value is modified by a datapack and stored as a decimal. 
Let me know if you need any more information from me.

Comment: Look up "CustomModelData".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only thing with color change using NBT is leather armor. This can be changed using an `item_modifier` using the set NBT property. Otherwise, you will need to use OptiFine or some other external utility.

However, if you are OK to use multiple textures, you can use the `CustomModelData` property that is available to all items. Here are some resources you can check out

[Item Command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/item) (used for triggering modifiers); [Item Modifiers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_modifier); [Item Modifier Generator](https://misode.github.io/item-modifier/)